# Create Any Number of Rects, be able to check how many I created, and Check their coordinates

Tags: python, pygame

Alright, so I'm creating a sort of puzzle game on a chess board. Up to this point, It's been relatively easy to write code for specific things and how they interact with other things, but  I've run into a problem adding impassable spaces because I can't seem to wrap my head around a way to be able to create to make one, or none, or 20 impassable objects. Because then I need to blit images onto the rects, and then also prevent movement based on the rect's coordinates. I can be more specific if needed. Just ask in comments. Thanks for help in advance.

edit: Someone requested more info.... so here's what I have so far... Someone else helped me write a function that generates rects for each space on the board...

```
def MakeBoard(upper_x=100, upper_y=100, size=100):
global ChessBoard
ChessBoard = []
for y in range(8):
    row = []
    for x in range(8):
        coords = (upper_x + x * size, upper_y + y * size)
        row.append(pygame.Rect(coords, (size, size)))
    ChessBoard.append(row)
return ChessBoard
```

So that function generates spaces on the board. Movement would be prohibited in this type of function, which generates the moves available to you. Basically it checks if the the destination coordinates fall between (1,1) and (8,8) and are therefore on the board. It can be referenced by ChessBoard[y][x]

```
def RookMove(RXM, RYM):
VarReset()
if (RXM + 3) >= 1 and (RXM + 3) <= 8:
    global ROption1Exists
    ROption1Exists = True
if (RXM-3) >= 1 and (RXM-3) <= 8:
    global ROption2Exists
    ROption2Exists = True
if (RYM+3) >= 1 and (RYM+3) <= 8:
    global ROption3Exists
    ROption3Exists = True
if (RYM-3) >= 1 and (RYM-3) <= 8:
    global ROption4Exists
    ROption4Exists = True
```

For prohibiting movement, I thought of adding another condition to the If statement that would be something like... having a list of the Coordinates of the impassable objects and checking to make sure none of the coordinates you would have to traverse match the elements in the list.

I think I could figure that part out myself, however. The main problem I'm having is generating the list without making a giant function of like 64 if statements for each space on the board.

Basically, what I'm looking for help with is how to, relatively simply,

A. blit images onto some coordinates that represent impassable terrain

B. populate a list with coordinates of impassable terrain, and then check to make sure that the coordinates on which the player will travel are not in the list. Or, in some other way, prohibit the movement of the player, within the context of the example function I provided, if a movement option would have him move through impassable terrain.

Comment: You really need to add more detail if you want useful answers. Try to include what you've tried already to solve this problem, what you expected the result to be, and what the actual result was.

Comment: I updated the post and hope that it is more informative now.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have two problems here, which should probably be two separate questions.

1. Determine a list of legal moves for a game piece.
2. Display the game board in pygame.

Here's some simple code which tests if a given board position is a valid move for a chess rook. It isn't perfect, but it may give you some ideas in how to approach this problem. Note, in a real game of chess you would also need to check that no other chess pieces are in the path of the target square.

Note also that the use of `global` variables should generally be avoided, and they certainly aren't needed here. Try instead to have your functions return a useful result that you calculate from the supplied parameters, without directly altering any data outside of themselves ("No side effects").

```
from collections import namedtuple

BoardPosition = namedtuple('BoardPosition', ['x', 'y'])

def isOnBoard(position):
    # return True if position is on the board, or else False
    return (position.x >= 0
        and position.x < 8
        and position.y >= 0
        and position.y < 8)

def sameX(posA, posB):
    # return True if both positions are on the same column
    return posA.x == posB.x

def sameY(posA, posB):
    # return True if both positions are on the same row
    return posA.y == posB.y

def isRookMove(rookPos, targetPos):
    # return True if the target position is on the game board
    # AND it is a valid move for the supplied rook position.
    return ((sameX(rookPos, targetPos) or sameY(rookPos, targetPos))
            and isOnBoard(targetPos))


# Now to test the code...
myRookPos = BoardPosition(0, 0)
print isRookMove(myRookPos, BoardPosition(0, 4)) # True  (same column)
print isRookMove(myRookPos, BoardPosition(2, 4)) # False 
print isRookMove(myRookPos, BoardPosition(0, 8)) # False (off the board)

# Here is one way to produce a list of all the valid moves for the test rook...
allLegalMoves = [BoardPosition(x, y) for x in range(8) for y in range(8)
        if isRookMove(myRookPos, BoardPosition(x, y))]
print allLegalMoves
```